# Refactoring Nested JavaScript Loops as CoffeeScript Comprehensions

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I have the following JavaScript that I'd like to translate to CoffeeScript:

```
function initPage() {
  var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
  labs.forEach(function(lab) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');

    // Create a header for each lab.
    var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    h2.innerHTML = lab.name;
    td.appendChild(h2);

    // Create a div for each machine in a given lab.
    for(i = lab.first; i <= lab.last; i++) {
      var machine = ((i < 10) ? "0" : "") + i;
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute('id', lab.name + "-" + machine);
      div.setAttribute('class', 'Grey');
      div.innerHTML = machine;
      td.appendChild(div);
    }

    // Append the new table data element to the table row.
    tr.appendChild(td);
  });
}
```

Right now my CoffeeScript translation looks something like this:

```
initPage = () ->
  tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0]
  labs.forEach (lab) ->
    td = document.createElement 'td'

    # Create a header for each lab.
    h2 = document.createElement 'h2'
    h2.innerHTML = lab.name
    tr.appendChild h2

    # Create a div for a machine given the machine number
    createDiv = (i) ->
      machine = if i < 10 then "0#{i}" else "#{i}"
      div = document.createElement 'div'
      div.setAttribute 'id', "#{lab.name}-#{machine}"
      div.setAttribute 'class', 'Grey'
      div.innerHTML = machine
      td.appendChild div

    # Create a div for each machine in a given lab
    createDiv machine for machine in [lab.first..lab.last]

    # Append the new table data element to the table row.
    tr.appendChild td
```

Is there a better, more idiomatic way to create the divs for each lab? Would it be better to avoid the createDiv function and do something like:

```
for i in [lab.first..lab.last]
  machine = if i < 10 then "0#{i}" else "#{i}"
  div = document.createElement 'div'
  div.setAttribute 'id', "#{lab.name}-#{machine}"
  div.setAttribute 'class', 'Grey'
  div.innerHTML = machine
  td.appendChild div
```

The [CoffeeScript language reference](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) says

> Most of the loops you'll write in CoffeeScript will be comprehensions over arrays, objects, and ranges.

and

> Comprehensions should be able to handle most places where you otherwise would use a loop, each/forEach, map, or select/filter

I'm new to the idea of list comprehensions and want to make sure that I'm translating this code in a way that leverages the strengths of CoffeeScript appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be better to avoid the createDiv function and just inline it?

Yes, that function looks a bit superfluous.

> I'm new to the idea of list comprehensions and want to make sure that I'm translating this code in an appropriate way

The aim of [list comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) is to build new lists, like `map` and `filter` would do it. And for which loops or (inappropriately) `forEach` was used often, manually `push`ing to an array.

However, your aim is not to create an array, but a DOM element only. Comprehensions don't help here, you will need to use them as loops to execute side effects.

Comment: +1 for explaining the proper use case for comprehensions, though you don't 'need to use loops', rather convention would reason to do that. There is no built in construct that prevents you from mutating state within a comprehension as they are just compiled into loops anyway. Another option: build up a buffer with a list comprehension, then write to the DOM once. Probably how I would approach it.

Comment: That's what I meant by "use them *as* loops", exactly. One just needs to care that they don't have an (implicit) return value.